# Design pattern as alternative to front-end template locals

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am relatively new to web development and am trying to figure out how to publish the server environment (dev, test, prod, etc) to the front-end.

I am using Node.js with Express, but the following code is closer to pseudo-code because is this is more of a design pattern question.

One way to publish the server environment with Express is to add this to the middleware:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){

   res.locals.env= {};  //we add the property env to locals

});
```

so now in a front-end template we can access the 'env' locals variable:

```
<div>
<% app.env = env %>  //hopefully 'env' will be available in a front-end template
</div>
```

I am not sure if the above is standard, but I feel like it certainly isn't ideal.

So I was thinking, perhaps we could do this instead, for either the first HTTP request, first socket request, or all requests(?):

//pseudo-code below

```
app.get('/', function(req,res,next){

  if(req.isAuthenticated()){

     socket.on('received-env-info', function(err,msg){
          res.render('index',{auth:true});
     }

     socket.emit('send-env-info', env);
   }
   else{
       res.render('index',{auth:false});
   }

});
```

in this way we can be assured that the client knows what the environment is (or any other server variables), before any html is sent to the server. (We assume there is some socket.io handler on the client that subsequently sets the global env on the client to the variable that was sent from the server).

is this a good design pattern, or a bad one?

extra credit: we could take the same idea, and use it for authentication too:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res,next){

  var infoForClient = {auth:null,env:env};  //should probably set auth to false for security but using 'null' for illustration purposes

     if(req.isAuthenticated()){
          infoForClient.auth = true;
    }
     else{
          infoForClient.auth = false;
    }

     socket.on('received-info-from-client', function(msg){
          if(msg === 'success'{   //some success message or another
              res.render('index',infoForClient);
           }
          else{
              infoForClient.auth = false;
              res.render('index',infoForClient);
          }

     }

     socket.emit('send-info-to-client', infoForClient);
   }
});
```

I just need to know if this is a sane approach or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work, but what's the gain vs

```
// B
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    info: info,
    html: template.render(info)
  });
});
```

or

```
// C
socket.on('get-index', function () {
  socket.emit('index', {
    info: info,
    html: template.render(info)
  });
});
```

or with the template moved client side, simply return the info.

Once an intelligent client is in the picture, rendering the template server-side is no longer needed in the first place.

So looking at the client code

```
// A
socket.on('send-info-to-client', function (infoForClient) {
  handleInfo(infoForClient);
  socket.emit('recieved-info-from-client', true);
});
request('/', function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) { return handleErr(err) }
  handleHtml(body);
});
```

handle info and handle html end up split in two.

```
// B
request('/', function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) { return handleErr(err) }
  handleInfo(body.info);
  handleHtml(body.html);
});

// C
socket.emit('get-index');
socket.on('index', function (msg) {
  handleInfo(msg.info);
  handleHtml(msg.html);
});
```

the handlers can be unified

and in the final case

```
// D
request('/', function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) { return handleErr(err) }
  handleInfo(body.info);
  handleHtml(template.render(body.info));
});
```

Comment: hmmm this makes me wonder if there is a front-end design pattern that ensures that global values are set before any re-rendering happens